# How to set the location of an image with exiftool?

Tags: exiftool

[ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) is a powerful tool for modifying meta data on images. What is the simple command line to specify the location for an image?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html) and [Forums](https://exiftool.org/forum) have many details, but the simple answer is

```
exiftool -XMP:GPSLatitude="43.836295" -XMP:GPSLongitude="-103.623030" <filename>
```